# Create 2 dimensional array on python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to join two arrays into a single two-dimensional array

```
array1 = ['12', '43', '53']
array2 = ['41', '32', '44']
```

should be like this:

```
array1 = [['12', '43', '53'],['41', '32', '44']]
```

I tried:

```
array1.append(array2)
```

but the result was this:

```
array1 = ['12', '43', '53','41', '32', '44']
```

Comment: That is not an array, that is a list.

Comment: That was absolutely **not** the result of `array1.append(array2)`

Comment: If you did indeed get `['12', '43', '53','41', '32', '44']`, the command you used was `array1.extend(array2)` - not the same as `.append`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

```
array1 = ['12', '43', '53']
array2 = ['41', '32', '44']
array3 = [array1,array2]
```

also your example works fine. I think you used `.extend`

```
array1.append(array2)
```

output

```
array3 = [['12', '43', '53'],['41', '32', '44']]
```